# HTML getting escaped

Tags: laravel

I'm using the BeautyMail package to send email via Laravel 8.83.  I'm using:

```
@if ($pasted_content)
   {!! $pasted_content !!}
 @else
   <a href="{{ $temporary_url }}">{{ $temporary_url }}</a> (This link is valid for 7 days)
 @endif
```

in my blade.php, however the $pasted_content is being converted to the corresponding HTML entities.  Is there a way that I can force it to keep the HTML tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade's `{{`/`}}` escape the value and it is expected behavior. To output contents raw, you need to use `{!!`/`!!}` respectively.

See official docs chapter ["Displaying Unescaped Data"](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data).

Comment: are you sure `$pasted_content` value is not already escaped prior passing it to the template?

Comment: I am.  I did a Log on it and it looks like proper HTML.

Comment: how did you view the log? In the browser? If so, if you saw `proper HTML` then you saw it escaped, otherwise you'd not see the markdown but its rendering

Comment: Martin,  I have to apologize as I was escaping the wrong variable (face-palm).  However I'll leave your correct solution in case it helps someone else.